# IBMQ - Total samples exceeds the maximum number of samples for channel [8002]

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, openpulse

I'm trying to run some pulse schedules on `ibmq_bogota` but I'm running into this error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

There are 99 "circuits"/pulse schedules in this job. When I try to queue just a subset of 98 schedules^ instead, I get

> Total samples exceeds the maximum number of samples for channel CR1_0. (413168 > 258144) [8002]

So it seems like this might be a problem with having too many circuits in one job.

My questions are: what is a 'sample' in a channel, what is channel CR1_0, how can I calculate how many samples is in my job, and where can I find the maximum 258144 number for this backend.

The `max_experiments` of this backend is

```
>>> backend.configuration().max_experiments
900
```

and `max_shots` is

```
>>> backend.configuration().max_shots
8192
```

Thanks.

---

Using [`IBMQJobManager`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.html) does not work either, but at least I can set `max_experiments_per_job` to some very low bound so that all the jobs will execute.

---

One of my pulse schedules:

[image: Diagram of pulse schedule]

The others are basically the same with different initial u1 pulse duration.

^I've tried queuing a single pulse schedule with the longest u1 pulse duration and that was successful, so I guess it's not related to how long each individual pulse schedule is.

Comment: Hi, I don't know much about Pulse, but the error code 8002 seems to have as a solution "reduce number of samples below specified limit" (see [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/errors#id6)). Also, I just looked at it a few hours ago and never used it, but thought about it when seeing your problem, the [job manager](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.html?highlight=ibmqjobmanager#qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager), that could help solve your problem since it runs jobs based on "backend restrictions". Hope it works :)

Comment: @Lena Thanks for your suggestion. I was going to try job manager later if there's no other ideas. A bit new to this qiskit and ibmq stuff so still trying to figure out the details and "best practices" haha.